# Can i combine or concatenate column values in oracle as shown below

Tags: sql, oracle

Base Data:

```
 DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        20 SMITH
        30 ALLEN
        30 WARD
        20 JONES
        30 MARTIN
        30 BLAKE
        10 CLARK
        20 SCOTT
        10 KING
        30 TURNER
        20 ADAMS
        30 JAMES
        20 FORD
        10 MILLER
```

Desired Output:

```
    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 SMITH,FORD,ADAMS,SCOTT,JONES
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,MARTIN,TURNER,JAMES,WARD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify what version of Oracle but in Oracle 11g, you can use [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm):

```
select DEPTNO,
  listagg(ENAME, ',') within group (order by ENAME) as ename
from yourtable
group by DEPTNO
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b460/2)

In Oracle 10g you can use [`wm_concat()`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

```
select DEPTNO,
  wm_concat(ENAME) as ename
from yourtable
group by DEPTNO
```

You should also be able to use the following:

```
SELECT LRRID,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(CDSID,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS elements
FROM   
(
  SELECT LRRID,
    CDSID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LRRID ORDER BY CDSID) AS curr,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LRRID ORDER BY CDSID) -1 AS prev
  FROM WLRR_LRR_NOTIFY_TABLE
)
GROUP BY LRRID
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND LRRID = PRIOR LRRID
START WITH curr = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3467d/5)

Comment: I use Oracle 11G...but i get ORA00923 from keyword not found where expected error.

Comment: @ashwinsakthi Are you using this code exactly?  This is working in the following demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b996/1

Comment: select LRRID,
listagg(CDSID, ',') within group (order by CDSID) as CDSIDs
from WLRR_LRR_NOTIFY_TABLE
group by LRRID

Comment: Hi Bluefeet...can you help me with this..http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3467d/1

Comment: It is working in sql fiddle...but not working in my DB

Comment: sorry mate my DB is 10G

Comment: @ashwinsakthi Then the second method should work for you.

Comment: awesome mate...the partition query worked..thanks for your help.

Comment: @ashwinsakthi Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Ummm try this..

```
SELECT DEPTNO, LISTAGG(ENAME, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ENAME) AS ENAME
FROM   <TABLE-NAME>
GROUP BY DEPTNO;
```